# RegEx like conditional statements (with tags)

Tags: objective-c, regex, tags, conditional-statements, shortcut

I have 12 images and I wanted to check if they were all invisible. So I would have to check if they were either hidden or if they just had no content in them. Rather than check if each one was hidden or if it had not content I decided to add up all of the values of the booleans 

e.g. `[__ isHidden]` will return 1 or 0 which is a number so we can use it in a math equation!

And then take the sum of those booleans and check if they were greater than or equal to 12, meaning that at least 12 photos were hidden, had no content **(*There is no case where the photo would be hidden AND have no content)**

Here is the conditional statement:

```
if (((drawImage12.image == nil) + (drawImage11.image == nil) + (drawImage10.image == nil) + (drawImage9.image == nil) + (drawImage8.image == nil) + (drawImage7.image == nil) + (drawImage6.image == nil) + (drawImage5.image == nil) + (drawImage4.image == nil) + (drawImage3.image == nil) + (drawImage2.image == nil) + (drawImage1.image == nil) + ([drawImage12 isHidden]) + ([drawImage11 isHidden]) + ([drawImage10 isHidden]) + ([drawImage9 isHidden]) + ([drawImage8 isHidden]) + ([drawImage7 isHidden]) + ([drawImage6 isHidden]) + ([drawImage5 isHidden]) + ([drawImage4 isHidden]) + ([drawImage3 isHidden]) + ([drawImage2 isHidden]) + ([drawImage1 isHidden])) >= 12) {
   //do stuff here
}
```

My question is: is there an easier way to write this kind of like RegEx works, maybe using an object's `tag` property?

Like: (And this is not real code, just an example)

 `if (((drawImage[1-12].image == nil) + (drawImage[1-12].hidden == YES)) >= 12) {`
which translated to english would be like "If all 12 images are either blank OR hidden"

Comment: [Do not use signatures, salutations or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not much shorter, but maybe you'd prefer this:

```
NSArray *drawImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:drawImage12, drawImage11, drawImage10, etc, nil];
bool thereIsAProblem = NO;

for (UIImage *drawImage drawImages) {
    if (!drawImage.image || drawImage.hidden) {
      thereIsAProblem = true;
      break;
    }
}

if (!thereIsAProblem) {
  //do stuff here
}
```

If you preferred to go down the adding up values route, you could always just do something like:

```
for (UIImage *drawImage drawImages) {
  if (!drawImage.image || drawImage.hidden) {
    someVariable += 1;
  }
}

if (someVariable == 12) {
  //do stuff
}
```

**Note:** Above code isn't tested

Comment: Ah! Very cool! The second bit of code should work! (In your first bit of code I think it will call thereIsAProblem is just 1 image is invisible, I only need that method called though when ALL images are invisible because then I know the user is seeing a blank screen! +1, I will leave this question un-answered for now to see if anyone has more RegEx styled answers. Thankyou so much for yours, it is very neat! I liked the `, etc., nil` in your array... made me chuckle haha!